# I want help in a query: What is the average population of the districts in each country?

Tags: sql

I have only one City Table :

| ID | Name | Country Code | District | Population |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | Rotterdam | NLD | Zuid-Holland | 593321 |
| 3878 | Scottsdale | USA | Arizona | 202705 |
| 3965 | Corona | USA | California | 124966 |
| 3973 | Concord | USA | California | 121780 |
| 3977 | Cedar Rapids | USA | Iowa | 120758 |
| 3982 | Coral Springs | USA | Florida | 117549 |
| 1613 | Neyagawa | JPN | Osaka | 257315 |
| 1630 | Ageo | JPN | Saitama | 209442 |

The Expected Result is :

| countrycode | avg(population) |
| --- | --- |
| JPN | xxxxxx |
| NLD | xxxxxxx |
| USA | xxxxxxx |

I have used the shared code but was not getting the expected answer:

```sql
select avg(population)
from city
where countrycode='JPN' and 'USA' and 'NLD'
group by district;
```

The above code gives me a blank result " avg(population)" - blank.

I am using SQL workbench

Comment: MySQL Workbench, as its name implies, is an IDE for MySQL, not SQL Server. Which are you **really** using?

Comment: Try putting "countrycode" into the SELECT statement, too.

Comment: select countrycode, avg(population)
from city
group by countrycode;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```sql
select countrycode, avg(population) as avg_population
from city
where countrycode in('JPN', 'USA', 'NLD')
group by countrycode;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job :

```
select countrycode, avg(population)
from city
where countrycode in('JPN','USA','NLD')
group by countrycode;
```

Comment: This code gave me an error 1064